# How to find repetitive records of the parent table based on their sub-records in the child table?

Tags: sql

I have two tables in SQL, one is the `Products` table which has the records of some products; every product is unique by its `Id`.

The other table is `Ingredients` table which consists of the ingredients of every product; it contains columns like `GoodsCode`, `Amount` and so on. So this table has the `Id` column of an entry in the `Products` table as foreign key.

All I want is to have a query to take the `Id` of a product as an input and give all the Ids of the other products with the same ingredients as the output (it can be a table-valued function).

The goal is to find the Ids of the same products based on their ingredients.

I wonder if it is a good straight solution for that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the ingredientIds of ingredients in your product:

```
Select ingredientId from ingredients where productId = <your product id>
```

Then you need to use those ingredients to find other similar products

```
select productId from products p 
join ingredients i on p.productId = i.productId 
where i.ingredientId in (
    Select ingredientId from ingredients where productId = <your product id>)
```

This won't quite give you exact match, because it will only filter out those products which have an ingredient that is not included in your original product..

You might want to look into ALL function to get exact match, maybe something like

```
select productId from products p
join ingredients i on p.productId = i.productId 
where i.ingredientId = ALL(
    Select ingredientId from ingredients where productId = <your product id>)
```

**Update**

To modify the sameness of ingredients, just change the inner query to only include ids of ingredients which you want to consider.. so if you want all ingredients which have the same Amount and GoodsCode to be included you can try something like this to get those IDs:

```
select ingredientId from ingredients i1 join (
    select GoodsCode, Amount from ingredients i where i.productId = <your prod id>) as i2 
on i1.GoodsCode = i2.GoodsCode and i1.Amount = i2.Amount
```

Then plugging in this subquery into the above we get:

```
select productId from products p
join ingredients i on p.productId = i.productId 
where i.ingredientId = ALL(
    select ingredientId from ingredients i1 join (
        select GoodsCode, Amount from ingredients i 
            where i.productId = <your prod id>) as i2 
        on i1.GoodsCode = i2.GoodsCode and i1.Amount = i2.Amount
    )
```

Comment: then! what does exactly your query do?! You are just returning the inner join of Products and Ingredients where productId = <my product id>

Comment: which database engine are you using?

Comment: I mentioned in the question,SQL.

Comment: tnx for the answer, but the sameness of the ingredients are not just based on ingredientId. It is based on Amount and GoodsCode fields.

Comment: updated with instructions to modify sameness criteria